# Unable predict the text for sentiment analysis using pickle file for multiple comments

Tags: python, pandas, list, machine-learning, nlp

**Unable predict the text for sentiment analysis using pickle file for multiple comments**

For example i have code below which returns sentiment for only one comment

```
vectorizer = pickle.load(open(vectorizer_path,'rb'))
model = pickle.load(open(model_path,'rb'))

pred = model.predict(vectorizer.transform(["My name is rohit"]))[0]
print ("predicted class is : ", pred)
```

And the output is :

```
predicted class is :  Positive
```

If i have a dataframe with one column which consists multiple comments

```
    Comments
0   My name is rohit
1   You're too bad
2   I like your voice
3   I'm very sick
4   I'm suffering with cold
```

I've iterated the above rows present in comments column and appended it to empty list

```
word = []

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    word.append(str(row[0]))
```

How to predict all the sentiments for the above rows once at a time? What changes should i make in the below code

```
pred = model.predict(vectorizer.transform(["My name is rohit"]))[0]
print ("predicted class is : ", pred)
```

Comment: Can you share the error you get in the post?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my code. Please help me with this

Comment: Have you tried to apply `model.predict` on each comment in a for loop or a list comprehension?